# Nested loops in template

Tags: django, templates

I have a  loop in my Django template which displays the data from database

```
{% for i in prosize %}
            <li><a  class="order" id="{{i.option1}}" href="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>
" >{{i.option1}}</a></li>
        {% endfor %}
```

I need to change the style for the **first element** and **remains** the same for the others like for the first element the background colour will be black and for others it should be any other colour.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `{% if forloop.first %}` to check if this is the first iteration.

A full list of forloop constructs can be found here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#for

Answer (score 0):

```
{{ forloop.counter }}
```

should give you the count of the iteration. If it's one, you should be dealing with your first element.

Comment: can i get the first element in loop without specifing ==1

this is my orignal code


 {% if i.num_in_stock > 0 %}

      {{ forloop.counter }} 
      <li><a  class="order" id="{{i.option1}}" href="javascript:setSize('{{i.option1}}')">{{i.option1}}</a></li>
      {% else %}
      <li><a style="background-color:#c2c2c2;color:#000;" href="#myModal" role="button" data-toggle="modal" >{{i.option1}}</a></li>
      {% endif %} 
        {% endfor %}

Answer (score 0):

you can add a custom css class for first element

```
{% for i in prosize %}
  <li {% if forloop.first %}class="red"{% endif %}>
      <a class="order" id="{{i.option1}}">{{i.option1}}</a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

and css

```
.red {
  background: red;
}
```